# How to sort search result by post_title, then by post_content

Tags: php, wp-query, sql

How to sort search result by post_title, then by post_content
For example - if i search for word "Ball" i want to get results where "ball" exists in title, then the results where "ball" exists in the content.

With the help of ChatGPT i got this selution. But this is a normal sort by title not by search results

```
function custom_search_query($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('orderby', 'post_title');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','custom_search_query');
```

**PS:**
Am using this api for searching
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?search=text

Comment: ChatGPT hasn't given you anything close to what you're asking for (surprise, surprise). You want to weight search results with a higher weight for matches in the title. WordPress already sorts search results this way. Matches in the post title are given a higher priority than matches in the content: https://wpsmackdown.com/wordpress-search-improvements-3-7/

Comment: For some reason this is not correct in my case.

Anyway i wrote raw SQL with `order by case`